# Finding the Limit for (x, y) → (0, 0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm working on a math problem and could use some help evaluating the limit:

$$
\lim_{{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}} \frac{x^2y - xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}
$$

If anyone could provide a step-by-step solution, I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried to solve this limit through comparison; I know from online calculators that the result should be 0.

$$
\left|\frac{x^{2}y-xy^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\le\frac{\left|x^{2}y-xy^{2}\right|}{x^{2}}\le\dotsm
$$

But I don't know how to proceed.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi welcome to MSE. Please add stuff you have tried, where exactly you are stuck, conjectures you have... Just posing a question is not a [good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can continue using the triangle inequality:

$$
\left| \frac{x^{2}y - xy^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \right| \le \frac{\left| x^{2}y - xy^{2} \right|}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \le \frac{\left| x^{2}y \right| + \left| xy^{2} \right|}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \le \frac{\left| x^{2}y \right|}{x^{2}+y^{2}} + \frac{\left| xy^{2} \right|}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \le \frac{\left| x^{2}y \right|}{x^{2}} + \frac{\left| xy^{2} \right|}{y^{2}} = \left| y \right| + \left| x \right| \underset{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{\longrightarrow} 0.
$$

If you need assistance with any further steps, please let me know.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$(x \pm y)^2=x^2+y^2 \pm 2xy \ge 0;$
$|x^2+y^2| \ge |2xy| \ge |xy|$;

Numerator:

$|xy||x-y| \le$

$|x^2+y^2|(|x|+|y|)$

Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I could finish it. thank you

Comment: @bladee. A pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Change of variables can help too.

$x=r \cos \theta$

$y= r \sin \theta$

$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$\theta = \arctan(y/x)$

$\frac{x^2y-y^2x}{x^2+y^2} =r(\cos^2\theta \sin \theta - \sin^2\theta\cos\theta)$

$r|\cos\theta \sin \theta (\cos \theta - \sin \theta)|<r\sqrt{2}$

So it suffices to find limit as $r \to 0$.

Suppose $|r| \le \epsilon/\sqrt{2}\implies |r\sqrt{2}|<\epsilon\implies |\frac{x^2y-y^2x}{x^2+y^2}|< \epsilon$

So by the delta-epsilon definition of a limit, the limit is $0$.