# $\lim_{{(x, y) \to (a, b)}} \frac{x^3 + y^3}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm grappling with a mathematical problem and could use some assistance. Could you help me evaluate the following limit?

$$
\lim_{{(x, y) \to (a, b)}} \frac{x^3 + y^3}{x^2 + y^2}
$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are constants. I appreciate any insights or step-by-step explanations you can provide.

I have been trying to solve this limit, and the issue arises when $a=b=0$. I couldn't figure out how to proceed with the resolution.

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: homogeneous, enough to put it in polar coordinates  to get bounds of the expression near the origin

Comment: @WillJagy Could you include a little more details please?

Comment: @bladee Just use polar coordinates and see what the expression turns into. You should get $r(\sin^{3}(\theta)+\cos^{3}(\theta))$. Can you now say what happens to this as $r\to 0$?

Comment: You can apply exactly the same technique as in your other question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an issue at a single point $ ( a , b ) $, then it often helps to switch to polar coordinates $ x = a + r \cos \theta $ and $ y = b + r \sin \theta $; then $ ( x , y ) \to ( a , b ) $ is the same direction as $ r \to 0 $.  Here, there's no problem except when $ ( a , b ) = ( 0 , 0 ) $, so we use the usual polar coordinates $ ( x , y ) = ( r \cos \theta , r \sin \theta ) $.

So $$ \frac { x ^ 3 + y ^ 3 } { x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 } = \frac { ( r \cos \theta ) ^ 3 + ( r \sin \theta ) ^ 3 } { ( r \cos \theta ) ^ 2 + ( r \sin \theta ) ^ 2 } = \frac { r ^ 3 \cos ^ 3 \theta + r ^ 3 \sin ^ 3 \theta } { r ^ 2 \cos ^ 2 \theta + r ^ 2 \sin ^ 2 \theta } = r \frac { \cos ^ 3 \theta + \sin ^ 3 \theta } { \cos ^ 2 \theta + \sin ^ 2 \theta } \text . $$  As $ r \to 0 $, this will approach $ 0 $ as long as the factor with $ \theta $ remains bounded.  Since sines and cosines are bounded by $ \pm 1 $, you can be confident that the numerator always lies between $ - 2 $ and $ 2 $ (you don't need the precise bounds).  The denominator can cause more problems, since it needs to be bounded *away* from zero rather than *towards* zero.  Fortunately, this denominator is always $ 1 $, so it is bounded away from zero.

To be more explicit, you can write it out like this: $$ \Biggl \lvert \frac { x ^ 3 + y ^ 3 } { x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 } \Biggr \rvert = \lvert r \rvert \frac { \lvert \cos ^ 3 \theta + \sin ^ 3 \theta \rvert } { \lvert \cos ^ 2 \theta + \sin ^ 2 \theta \rvert } \leq \lvert r \rvert \frac { 1 ^ 3 + 1 ^ 3 } 1 = 2 \lvert r \rvert \to 0 \text , $$ so $ \frac { x ^ 3 + y ^ 3 } { x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 } \to 0 $.

The same technique will work for [Finding the Limit for (x, y) → (0, 0)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845876/finding-the-limit-for-x-y-%e2%86%92-0-0/) as well.  Instead of $ \lvert \cos ^ 3 \theta + \sin ^ 3 \theta \rvert \leq 1 ^ 3 + 1 ^ 3 = 2 $, you have $ \lvert \cos ^ 2 \theta \sin \theta - \cos \theta \sin ^ 2 \theta \rvert \leq 1 ^ 2 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 ^ 2 = 2 $, that's all.  (Notice that minus becomes plus when estimating an absolute value: $ \lvert u - v \rvert \leq \lvert u \vert + \lvert v \rvert $.)

Just be careful if your denominator is something like $ \sin \theta + \cos \theta $, which *can* be zero; then the $ \theta $ factor might be unbounded, and you can't conclude that the limit is zero.  (In that case, try approaching in a direction that makes the denominator approach zero, and see if you can prove that the limit doesn't exist.)  Also, if the expression isn't homogeneous in $ r $, you can leave extra factors of $ r $ in the numerator (where you want things to approach zero) but not in the denominator (where you need things to stay away from zero).

Comment: thank you very much for the very detailed answer

Comment: You're welcome, I hope that you find it useful for similar problems!

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = (x+y)\left(1-\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

When $(x, y)\to (0, 0)$ we have $x+y\to 0$ and $\displaystyle 1-\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ is limited (by $AM\ge GM$), therefore

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} = 0$$

Comment: what is $AM\ge GM$ ?

Comment: Its the mean inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality